# Incorrect Syntax near the Keyword Select

Tags: sql-server

Create a function that when passed in a VendorID will return the balance remaining for the vendor. Use this function in a query to return all the CA vendors and their balances

```
USE AP

GO

CREATE FUNCTION fnBalanceVendor

(@vendorid INT)

    Returns Table

RETURN (SELECT Vendors.VendorID, (InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal) AS Balance

        FROM Vendors Join Invoices ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID

        WHERE Vendors.VendorID = @vendorid)





SELECT *

FROM Vendors INNER JOIN dbo.fnBalanceVendor(8) AS ca ON Vendors.VendorID = ca.VendorID

WHERE VendorState = 'CA'
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fnBalanceVendor, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 2]

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Unsure what I am doing wrong here any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Missing semi colon after the function return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest sticking a "go" to close out the batch after the RETURN in your CREATE FUNCTION statement, so:

```
USE AP
GO
CREATE FUNCTION fnBalanceVendor
(@vendorid INT)
    Returns Table
RETURN (SELECT Vendors.VendorID, (InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal) AS Balance
        FROM Vendors Join Invoices ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
        WHERE Vendors.VendorID = @vendorid)

GO

SELECT *
FROM Vendors INNER JOIN dbo.fnBalanceVendor(8) AS ca ON Vendors.VendorID = ca.VendorID
WHERE VendorState = 'CA'
```

Comment: @MichaelGonzalez If this solved your issue.  Be sure to ACCEPT the answer.